# How to use thread in Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I want to check users' subscribed dates for certain period. And send mail to users whose subscription is finishing (ex. reminds two days).
I think the best way is using thread and timer to check dates. But I have no idea how to call this function. I don't want to make a separate program or shell. I want to combine this procedure to my django code. I tried to call this function in my settings.py file. But it seems it is not a good idea. It calls the function and creates thread every time I imported settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [Django-cron](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/) is much easier and simple

**EDIT: Added a tip**

```
from django_cron import cronScheduler, Job
class sendMail(Job):
       # period run every 300 seconds (5 minutes)
        run_every = 300

        def job(self):
                # This will be executed every 5 minutes
                datatuple = check_subscription_finishing()
                send_mass_mail(datatuple)
//and just register it             
cronScheduler.register(sendMail)
```

Answer (score 3):

That's case for `manage.py` command called periodically from cron. [Oficial doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) about creating those commands. [Here](http://oebfare.com/blog/2008/nov/03/writing-custom-management-command/) bit more helpful.

If you want something simpler then [django-command-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/) has commands for managing [django jobs](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/JobsScheduling).

Answer (score 2):

if you need more then only this one asynchronous job have a look at [celery](http://celeryproject.org).