# Unable to use Python's threading.Thread in Django app

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-views

I am trying to create a web application as a front end to another Python app.  I have the user enter data into a form, and upon submitting, the idea is for the data to be saved in a database, and for the data to be passed to a thread object class.  The thread is something that is strictly kicked-off based on a user action.  My problem is that I can import threading, but cannot access threading.Thread.  When the thread ends, it will update the server, so when the user views the job information, they'll see the results.

View:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def createNetworkView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # grab my variables from POST
        job = models.MyJob()
        # load my variables into MyJob object
        job.save()
        t = ProcessJobThread(job.id, my, various, POST, inputs, here)
        t.start()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/viewJob?jobID=" + str(job.id))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

My thread class:

```
import threading # this works
print "About to make thread object" # This works, I see this in the log
class CreateNetworkThread(threading.Thread): # failure here
    def __init__(self, jobid, blah1, blah2, blah3):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        doCoolStuff()
        updateDB()
```

I get:

```
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    cannot import name Thread
```

However, if I run python on the command line, I can import threading and also do from threading import Thread. What's the deal?

I have seen other things, like [How to use thread in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583567/how-to-use-thread-in-django) and [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) but that seemed overkill, and I don't see how that example could import threading and use threading.Thread, when I can't.
Thank you.

Edit: I'm using Django 1.4.1, Python 2.7.3, Ubuntu 12.10, SQLite for the DB, and I'm running the web application with *./manage.py runserver*.

Comment: What's the name of the thread class module file?
If you've named it 'threading.py' you are hiding the python threading module.

Comment: Please show the actual full traceback. The code you show isn't causing that error, as you don't import Thread (you'd get AttributeError instead).

Comment: @DanielRoseman: No, if you did `from threading import Thread` you _would_ get an `ImportError` that looks exactly like the one he sees. (But that doesn't change your larger point that the code he showed us is not the code he actually ran.)

Comment: @abarnert that's my point, in the coffee he shows he only does `import threading`, which won't give that error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: But you said if he imported `Thread` he'd get `AttributeError` instead. That's not true; he'd get `ImportError`, exactly as he shows. Again, that doesn't change your larger point that what he showed us is not what he's running… but it's generally a bad idea to confuse people who haven't yet learned how to ask a question.

Comment: @abarnert sorry to quibble, but I didn't say that... I said the code he showed would give AttributeError.

Comment: Correct, the code I am running isn't what I posted.  This is to avoid me possibly getting in trouble for "releasing" code.  However, the error message said that the view couldn't be found because it included another .py file where I did the "import threading" then tried to use "threading.Thread".  Thus creating a misleading error.  I was trying to be straight to the point. @AndreaDiPersio- you were right, I had my threading code in a subdirectory and in a file called threadying.py.  Even after I fixed that, my error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly issue I had.  First, I had made a file called "threading.py" and someone suggest I delete it, which I did (or thought I did).  The problem was because of me using Eclipse, the PyDev (Python) plugin for Eclipse only deleted the threading.py file I created, and hides the *.pyc file.  I had a lingering threading.pyc file lingering around, even though PyDev has an option that I had enabled to delete orphaned .pyc files.